Ionic input ngModel two way Data Binding or Add number format
<ion-col size="4">
  <ion-input
    class="input-field"
    style="--padding-end: 20px; text-align: end;"        
    [(ngModel)]="discountPercent"
    (ngModelChange)="onDiscountPercentChange()"
    type="text"
    appDecimalPlaces="2">
    <p slot="end">%</p>
  </ion-input>
</ion-col>

Your text:
[(ngModel)]="discountAmount"
I want to add this place format function
getFormatedNumber(saleDecimals)
How can I solve this?

what exactly do you mean you want too add function?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

First of all the question feels like incomplete but i assume you need to format the model value from input using your custom function
To do that, we can leverage the already called onDiscountPercentChange and with in that just run the getFormatedNumber(saleDecimals)
like in
onDiscountPercentChange(): void {
// run the format fn

this.getFormatedNumber(2);
}


I have discount amount & discount percentage , i add gfN function in onDiscontChange(), both UI cannot change. getFormatedNumber(x) is changeable by ApI respond.

@Emerald, i still little confused on the objective here, what i understood is you want have a watcher on model change and when the user input is done you need to call and API for getFormatedNumber(x) and the server given the updated input for the input and then bind it here. is it correct ?
